# how to record all appears in swf using AS3?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I am creating a card game and want to record all the movements of cards after login and choosing the seat.

can anyone help in this that how could i record all appears in swf??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

then you need to create some class:

`IterationTracking` or something, and after each iteration in your game just record them to array, or send to server

```
IterationTracking.addAction ( Iterationtracking.TYPE_SEAT_CHANGE, userID, [table, seat] );

IterationTracking.addAction ( Iterationtracking.TYPE_CARD_RECEIVED, userID, [H_Q] );

IterationTracking.addAction ( Iterationtracking.TYPE_CARD_FOLD, userID, [H_Q, H_4] );

IterationTracking.addAction ( Iterationtracking.TYPE_CARD_ON_TABLE, userID, [H_Q] );

function addAction ( type : String, userID : int, data : Array )
{
    var action:Object = new Object();
        action.userID = userID;
        action.type = type;
        action.data = data;

    actions.push ( action );

    // and if you need to do something on specific iteration then just switch case solution.
    switch ( type )
    {
        case TYPE_CARD_RECEIVED :
            //your actions
            break;

        case TYPE_CARD_FOLD :
            //your actions
            break;

        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to record the game directly, without sending or recieving data in array??

Comment: what do you mean by record? like video stream?

Comment: i just want to make a .flv video while swf is playing on browser, could it is possible by writing code inside .as file.